# How to analyze big excel data fast?

Tags: database, vba, excel, ms-office

I have an excel database with many tables(over 40+) that all have annual financial data for over 10k stocks.
They all look like this:

[image: Like This]

This excel file has over 100MB of data because every data set has over 10.000 rows with like 50 columns (for 50years in the past).

Now I want to calculate averages and other key figures for every stock and every data set (for example 5 Year average profit). So I need some of the data of last years for every stock and calculate an average.

[image: basic example of analysis table]

The problem is that the excel query function isn't doing well with such mass of data and doing the same averages every table is too much work. Especially if next year 2018 is added as a column and I have to change everything again. However the averages should update if I change something in the data source.

Comment: The best way is to import that big data into data model of a new workbook and then you can insert a pivot table based on tables in the data model with the help of PowerPivot Add-in and you may then also utilize the power of dax functions. And since this new workbook will contain all your data in the data model, the file size of this workbook will be reasonable as well.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to fit the guidelines for the community (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That said, this sounds more like either a database problem, or a modeling problem. I am not very well versed in databases or their structures so I cant speak to that end. On the modeling end though you have a few solutions. You can learn about VBA Arrays, Dictionaries, Classes, etc and (over time) develop a solution that will be efficient, dynamic, and scalable. On the other hand, you can look for performance improvements within PivotTables, Calculations, etc.

Comment: A note on using VBA to do modeling: in my own work I worked on a project where I aggregated, modeled, and analyzed 670MB of data that spread over two years. The capability is there, but you just need to hunt down the skills to use that capability.

Comment: @sktneer but all the data in one workbook would probably make the whole excel sheet too slow. So it would work, but the performance wouldnt fit for daily use of the workbook.

Comment: @sktneer: I now know what you meant to do with powerPivot but I want to analyse the data row for row and not want to have a sum or average for the columns. So I would have to transpose all data sets.
But I want to have averages for the financial data of the last years for every stock seperately. Not averages for every year about all the stocks at once.